# I have a long expression which I want to simplify but assuming that an equation holds

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, sympy, simplify

In Mathematica, you can use the function FullSimplify[expression,assumptions] to simplify expressions using assumptions. For instance, if I do this:

FullSimplify[x^2-y^2,x^2-y^2==1],

then the result will be 1 because that's the 'simplest expression that is equivalent to the function I gave the software.

Now I need to do the same with Python, but I don't know how to do that. I have seen the documentation about the command sympy.refine on this page:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/refine.html

However, I haven't been able to use equalities as assumptions. It doesn't seem possible to assume things like that with the Q function.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
import sympy as sp
x,y=sp.symbols('x y')
sp.refine(x**2-y**2,x==y)
```

However, this gives me the following error: ValueError: Inconsistent assumptions

Does someone have any ideas about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Without some scope for what kind of expressions and assumptions you want to work with this is probably an unsolvable problem so I'll make some assumptions.

If you want to simplify a polynomial expression based on some other polynomial expression(s) being zero then you can do this in sympy using `ratsimpmodprime`:

```
In [1]: x, y = symbols('x, y')

In [2]: assumptions = [x**2 + y**2 - 1]

In [3]: expression = x**2 + y**2

In [4]: ratsimpmodprime(expression, assumptions)
Out[4]: 1
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#ratsimpmodprime

Answer (score 0):

I tried two approaches to the problem.

1. Assume that `x - y = 0`. This was the only way I could find to express the assumption that you want to make. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be smart enough to notice that this assumption allows it to substitute x for y.

   ```
   print("refine:", sp.refine(x**2-y**2,Q.zero(x-y)))
   ```

   This just returns the original expression.
2. Ask sympy to substitute the expression. This isn't as automatic - you're asking it to do the substitution instead of giving it the option of doing the substitution, but it does work for this toy example.

   ```
   expr = (x**2-y**2)
   print("substitution:", expr.subs(x**2-y**2, 1))
   ```

   prints 1.

Comment: The problem is that the simplifications are not always that easy. On the other hand, if you write something like this:
sp.refine((x+y)*(x-y),Q.zero(x-y)),
it gives you the same expression, so the only things that seems to work in your example is the substitution but, for instance, if you want to simplify something like this:
sp.refine(x^2*y+y^2*x,Q,zero(x*y+y^2)),
it doesn't recognize that the expression that you are using is equal to zero even using substitution, because you are not giving Python the explicit expression in which you are assuming something.